# Referencing a static attribute as initialisation for another static attribute in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a newby to python so please excuse the nomenclature stolen from other languages.  I have a class containing a "static" attribute (a list) and a static method.  I want to initialise the param to contain just a reference to the method:

```
class LogFilter(object):

    @staticmethod
    def _process_friendly_time(params):
        # process params
        pass

    param_processors = [
        LogFilter._process_friendly_time
    ]

# Later
for processor in LogFilter.param_processors:
    processor(params)
```

This code causes an error

```
NameError: name 'LogFilter' is not defined`.
```

But if I replace `LogFilter._process_friendly_time` with just `_process_friendly_time` then I later get an error...

```
TypeError: 'staticmethod' object is not callable
```

Is there a syntax that will let me do this, or must I move the static method outside the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to `LogFilter._process_friendly_time` at a point before `LogFilter` has been defined. At the point where you are currently declaring `param_processors`, you are midway through the definition of `LogFilter`: the definition is not yet complete.

You can move the field declaration to after the class.

```
class LogFilter:
    @staticmethod
    def _process_friendly_time(params):
        # process params
        pass

LogFilter.param_processors = [
    LogFilter._process_friendly_time
]
```

But consider whether you are actually getting any benefit out of using a static method. People often use them out of habit from other languages, but there is no benefit in this case: a standalone function would make more sense.